# how to bend a zipper to the contour of a jacket?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers

I would like to bend this zipper with the lowpoly object behind it, then I will apply to the jacket, I need to get clean shape with the zipper and contour.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way:

With the low poly object selected, go into *Edit* mode and select an edge loop that runs the length of the object(top to bottom). Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> then <kbd>Esc</kbd> to duplicate the the edge loop. Now press <kbd>P</kbd> and choose *Selection* to make the duplicate edge loop a separate object. Go back to *Object* mode and select the edge loop object. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and choose *Curve from Mesh* to make it into a Curve object. Select the zipper and add a *Curve* modifier to it with the edge loop object as the curve object and *Z* as the axis. Move the zipper on the Z axis until it fits the curve as you want.

Comment: when you said "o into Edit mode and select an edge loop that runs the length of the object(top to bottom)" ...you mean I select one edgeloops (the top edge loop and press control+"+" to expand the selection to the botton, but I prefer to use "a" to select all the edge loops? , sorry can not understand "runs the lengt of the object top to botton) I think you refer to select all the loops? thanks

Comment: No, I mean one line of edges, not all of them, just one vertical edge loop. You can use Alt + right click to select.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/sTSVN  look at the picture I ve choste a portion of edge loops of the lowpoly onem mesh , then I press "p" to separate , with the separate object I ve alted+c and chosen curve from mesn...check the modifier, I see ot but, the curve is similar...but It is seem as duplicate zipper or something weird, I ve not modifiers on the highpoly zipper.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/DHhXg  should I keep uncheck the box "conver to" ? this operation surge when I pressed "alt +c " to curve from mesh/text

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/IXdQP  this is the final solution : thanks :D

Comment: Well, you don't *need* the whole mesh, but I'm glad its working for you.